# OncreateView in Fragment is not calling with an singleInstance

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have two activities A and B which is extending one Base class Main and this Base class has one Framelayout in its layout which we are including in both of the activities A and B respective layouts.

I am checking the instance creation of fragment in Fragment which I am also inflating when I go into particular acitivity.

Here my code is :

```
public class BaseAcitvity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_base_acitvity);
    }
 }
```

Here is my FirstActivity::

```
public class FirstActivity extends BaseAcitvity {

    public FirstFragment firstFragment ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.firstactivitylayout);
        firstFragment = new FirstFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.card_view_layout,firstFragment).commit();

        Button buttonclick = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clickfirstactivity);
        buttonclick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent =  new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

}

public class SecondActivity extends BaseAcitvity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.secondactivity);

        FirstFragment fragment  = FirstFragment.getInstance();

        if(fragment == null)
        {
            fragment = new FirstFragment();
        }
        else { 
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        if(fragment !=null)
        {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.card_view_layout,fragment).commit(); 
        }
        }       

    }

}
```

And The Fragment is ::

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    private static FirstFragment currentInstance;

        FirstFragment () {
        currentInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized FirstFragment  getInstance() {
        if (currentInstance == null) 
            currentInstance = new FirstFragment();
        return currentInstance;
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

    }

}
```

Now my issue is if I have already created the instance of fragment in FirstActivity and checking the singleInstance in Fragment , the at the time of SecondActivity why the OncreatView() of fragment doesn't call where the instance gives not null.

Please help me..so that is there any way to call OncreateView() to inflate the fragmentLayout.

Comment: Never use static links for Activity, Fragments, Context like this...

Comment: well, he can use Application(Context) ... but not Activity(Context) ... also add Views to the numbers ...